# Enforcer rules are getting failed using maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, build, jira, maven-plugin

I have pom.xml with below plugin containing enforcement rule.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <rules>
            <banVersionDeps implementation="com.atlassian.maven.enforcer.BanVersionDeps">
                <bannedDependencyVersionRegexp>(?i)^.*-(rc|m)-?[0-9]+(-.+)?$</bannedDependencyVersionRegexp>
                <noFailReactorVersionRegexp>(?i)^.*-m-?[0-9]+(-.+)?$</noFailReactorVersionRegexp>
                <excludes>
                    <!-- Version being used is an RC with no newer GA release -->
                    <exclude>com.atlassian.crowd:*</exclude>
                    <exclude>net.fortuna.ical4j:ical4j</exclude>
                    <!-- Version being used is a milestone with no newer GA release -->
                    <exclude>com.atlassian.extension:*</exclude>
                    <exclude>com.atlassian.jira.plugins.inline-create:*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </banVersionDeps>
        </rules>
    </configuration> 
</plugin>
```

When I start build using this pom.xml I am facing below error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-versions) on project atlassian-jira-pageobjects: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-versions) on project atlassian-jira-pageobjects: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.EnforceMojo.execute(EnforceMojo.java:237)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
```

I am using `apache-maven-3.2.5` and `Java 8`.

Can someone guide me what is wrong in this configuration.

Comment: As the error message says, the cause is probably listed in the plugin output earlier in the log: `Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed.`

Comment: Yes you are right as er message I have add exclude rule and its working ... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was getting error for atlassian-browsers-windows I excluded that package and its working fine.

```
<excludes>
  <exclude>com.atlassian.browsers:atlassian-browsers-windows:*</exclude>
</excludes>
```